# class active en bootsrap en react con condicion

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

estoy haciendo una tabla en react con bootstrap 3 y tengo un problema al aplicar la clase active.
Deberia funcionar asi: cuando la condicion sea verdadera (cuando hoy sea lunes martes o miercoles), ni bien se carge la pagina se aplique la clase active en el th verdadero y luego que se aplique en otros th a medida que vaya haciendoles click. Hasta ahora logro que aparezca la clase active en el elemento true pero no se va cuando hago click en otro.. alguna sugerencia? muchas gracias!

este es el codigo:

```
<table className="nav nav-tabs table table-grid table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            { new Date().getDay() == '1' ? <th className='active'><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Lunes</a></th> : <th><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Lunes</a></th>  }   
            { new Date().getDay() == '2' ? <th className='active'><a href="#tab2default"  data-toggle="tab">Martes</a></th> : <th><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">Martes</a></th>  }   
            { new Date().getDay() == '3' ? <th className='active'><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab">Miércoles</a></th> : <th><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab">Miércoles</a></th>  } 
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: el problema es que si el dia de la fecha actual es el que ya viene marcado no importa cuantos clicks hagas siempre saldra active el inicial

Comment: Darien, gracias por tu respuesta.. si entiendo lo que decis, pero no hay manera de poder sacarlo cuando clickee en otro?

Comment: Hice un fiddle para que veas como se puede hacer https://jsfiddle.net/e4qcu9rh/4/ mira ver si te convence. Inicialmente saldria seleccionado el que corresponda con el dia en el que estamos, y a medida que navegues se van seleccionando

Answer (score 0):

Yo partiría declarando un estado donde marco el botón que quiero ver al inicar la página

```
const [buttonState, setButtonState] = React.useState(1)
```

Y luego actualizaría ese estado cada vez que escucha al evento `onClick`, puedes crear una función que quedaría así:

```
function handleClick(position){
 setButtonState(position)
}
. . .
<tr>
  <th><a className={buttonState === 1 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={handleClick(1)}>Lunes</a></th>
  <th><a className={buttonState === 2 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={handleClick(2)} >Martes</a></th>
  <th><a className={buttonState === 3 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={handleClick(3)} >Miércoles</a></th>
</tr>
```

O creando una función anónima

```
() => setButtonState(position)
```

Esto último te quedaría así:

```
const [buttonState, setButtonState] = React.useState(1)
render(){
 return(
   <table className="nav nav-tabs table table-grid table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><a className={buttonState === 1 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={() => setButtonState(1)}>Lunes</a></th>
          <th><a className={buttonState === 2 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={() => setButtonState(2)} >Martes</a></th>
          <th><a className={buttonState === 3 ? 'active' : ''} href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab" onClick={() => setButtonState(3)} >Miércoles</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>
 )
}
```